# how to get outer class name from inner enum

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

basicly what i want to do is written in code. so , is there a way with templates or with something else get outer class name in global function ? is there a way to get this code work?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    enum class B
    {
        val1, 
        val2
    };
    typedef B InnerEnum;
    static void f(InnerEnum val)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(val);
    }
};

template <typename T1>
void f(typename T1::InnerEnum val)
{
    T1::f(val);
}
int main()
{
    A::InnerEnum v = A::InnerEnum::val1;
    f(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in the main call it like: `f<A>(v);`

Comment: thanks for response. But the idea is to avoid outer class name usage

Comment: Ohh, I am not sure if it's possible, but you can typedef the outer class in the inner class. I think it should work. (not with enum tho)

Comment: You may want to use a namespace to contain the enum and other classes.  This would help with the encapsulation.  I prefer to keep my sanity and not use nested classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create trait for that and manually feed it:

```
template <typename T>
struct outer_class;

template <>
struct outer_class<A::B> { using type = A;};
```

And then

```
template <typename E>
void f(E val)
{
    using T = typename outer_class<E>::type;
    T::f(val);
}
```